# Show listBox.SelectedItems from a list of class objects

Tags: c#, winforms, class, listbox

I have a class with two members (name and value). Then I make a list of class objects that is filled from a textfile, so I have the names from the textfile in `name` and the value in `val`. This list is then used to make a `listbox` where I show all the names.

What I want to do is select multiple choices (name) from the `listbox` and then store the `val` of all of them in another list. Is this even possible?

I have tried with `SelectedItems` but that seems to only store the class object itself. For some reason though this:

```
foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

shows the first value of the selected items. If I select three names and the first of these has a value of `4` the result is `4 4 4`

Comment: how do you get your items into the `listBox` ? databinding? or do you fill it in a loop? did you override the `ToString()` method in your custom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cast the `selectedItem` to your class with the "two members". Then you can choose the `Value`:

```
foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    MyClass item = (MyClass)selectedItem
    textBox1.AppendText(item.Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

> If I select three names and the first of these has a value of 4 the result is 4 4 4

This happens because you don't use the iteration variable form the loop, but you use always the same `listBox1.SelectedValue`! This will be the first in the list of multi selected items